# I accidentally pulled a Shimano Deore brake lever with the rotor and pads off

Tags: brakes, shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

As the title says, I didn't realize pulling the brake will get it stuck in a closed position when wheel and pads are removed. Now the reason I'm asking this [previously asked question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-do-i-separate-disc-brake-pads-after-accidentally-pulling-the-front-brake-whi) is none of the answers worked for me.

So what happened? Step by step description of the (rather long) process:

- pads were worn off and started making funny noises, so I thought I'd remove them (first mistake)
- pulled the brake lever without any pads (second mistake)
- used the bike like this for a while
- I bought new pads, then removed the (back) wheel
- observed brakes stuck in a closed position, then I stupidly pulled the lever again (!)

I tried separating them with a wide range of tools, just they keep coming back in after a few seconds. Right after I stick something in between, push them apart from each other, if I wait a few seconds they are right back in the previous (wrong) position.

I'd like to know if there's anything I can do now, without bleeding the brake or anything I don't think I'm prepared for with my rather primitive tools.

Thank you all in advance for the answers, happy holidays & ride safe and fun!

**EDIT:** I just noticed [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16672/brake-pads-constantly-touching-the-rotor-because-piston-is-not-moving-back?rq=1) and its answers. I will try to leave it overnight, then attempt a bleeding if it doesn't work (I'm aware of the trapped air possibility).

**EDIT #2:** I attempted to spread apart the pistons again, and succeeded, then I stuck a solid piece of wood that barely fit between them. Left it like this overnight + a few hours later, then removed the wooden piece and left it free for a while. It seems the pistons got back to their normal position and all I needed was a bit of patience.

Thanks to all the people who replied on the linked questions, they really saved me some experiments and possibly more. Cheers!

Comment: How did you go with bleeding? If those answered worked for you can you mark this as a duplicate of the one that worked, please. If not, add any details you can and we'll see what we can come up with. Thanks.

Comment: @Mσᶎ I have edited the thing, not sure if I should mark it as a duplicate or not. What do you say? (or if you have the power to do it and consider it appropriate, do it)